# How to read csv files with beaker notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I use Beaker on Windows and start it up with gitbash with the following command:
./beaker.command.bat

If I want to read a .csv or excel file I have to place it in the same directory as  the beaker.command.bat.

How can I just the .csv files directly from their original location where the .bkr notebook script and the files are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just use the full directory path instead pointing to the file.